# the second feature could not see the defined varaible in the first feature when looping in js code

Tags: karate

I have one scenario, which need to loop an array as request parameter and pass to several separate sequential feature files, I am coding this by javascript loop, however, I found that the second feature can't see the variable  defined in the first feature.

**test1.feature**

```
Feature:  test1.feature

  Scenario:  test1.feature
    * def batch = 'define batch in test1 feature'
    * print ' test1 feature print batch: ',batch
```

**test2.feature**

```
Feature: test2 feature

  Scenario:  test2 feature
    * print 'print batch in test2 feature: ', batch
```

**loop.js**

```
function fn(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // var labName = arr[i];
        var res1 = karate.call('test1.feature');
        var res2 = karate.call('test2.feature');
    }
}
```

**demo.feature**

```
Feature: 循环读取所有的实验项目

  Scenario: 循环读取所有实验项目-配置文件

    * def arr = ['a','b']
    * def fun = read('loop.js')
    * call fun(arr)
```

to get it run, my test2.feature needs the the 'batch' value in the test1.feature when looping in javascript calling, however, the batch can not be seen in the test2.feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by default, you cannot see variables from one feature to another. This is obviously a very good thing.

I also recommend you *don't* use JS loops as far as possible. Please read the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

If you use the [`call` keyword](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files), the variables of the "calling" feature will be available in the "called" feature. This does not happen if you use `karate.call()` in JS. So you have to manually pass the variables you need like this:

```
var res1 = karate.call('test1.feature', { batch: batchIfDefined });
```

Comment: Ok, I get more clear about the call difference between  in JS  and not in js. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `karate.call(fileName, [arg])` if you want to pass variables. `arg` has to be a json if you need more than one variable.